# Android Raw folder files not copying correctly in release build

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

The raw folder files are not properly copying in release build, in debug its working correctly.

debug mode screenshot,

[image]

Release mode screenshot,

[image]

I think the file is copying but the content is 0 bytes.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: I had a similar issue, though not with flutter. It turns out a `keep.xml` file had `tools:shrinkMode="strict"` in it, and because the missing resources were addressed via `getIndentifier()` with dynamically-generated strings,  the shrinker didn't mark them as used. Adding these resources to the `tools:keep` in `keep.xml` solved this problem for me.